# ZeroMQ "lazy pirate pattern" fairly servicing multiple clients

Tags: c, server, client, message-queue, zeromq

I need an architecture for a single server reliably servicing multiple clients, with clients responding to unresponsive server similar to the lazy pirate pattern from the 0MQ guide (ie, they use zmq_poll to poll for replies; if timeout elapses, disconnect and reconnect the client socket and resend the request).

I took the "lazy pirate pattern" as a starting point, from the ZMQ C language examples directory (lpclient.c and lpserver.c).  Removed the simulated failure stuff from lpserver.c so that it would run normally without simulating crashes, as follows:

**Server has a simple loop:**

> 1. Read next message from the socket
> 2. Do some simulated work (1 second sleep)
> 3. Reply that it has serviced the request

**Client has simple loop:**

> 1. Send request to server
> 2. Run zmq_poll to check for response with some set timeout value
> 3. If timeout has elapsed, disconnect and reconnect to reset the connection and resend request at start of next iteration of loop

This worked great for one or two clients.  I then tried to service 20 clients by running them like:

$ ./lpserver &

$ for i in {1..20}
do
./lpclient &
done

The behaviour I get is:

> 1. Clients all send their requests and begin polling for replies.
> 2. Server does one second work on first message it gets, then replies
> 3. First client gets its response back and sends a new request
> 4. Server does one second work on second message it gets, then replies
> 5. Second client gets its response back and sends a new request
> 6. Server receives third client's request, but third client times out before work completes (2.5 second timeout, server work period is 1 second, so on the third request clients start dropping out).
> 7. Multiple clients (fourth through Nth) timeout and resend their requests.
> 8. Server keeps processing the defunct requests from the incoming message queue and doing work which hogs up the server, causing all clients to eventually timeout as it takes 20 seconds to get through each round of the queue with all of the defunct messages.

**Eventually all clients are dead and server is still spitting out responses to defunct connections.  This is terrible because the server keeps responding to requests the client has given up on (and therefore shouldn't expect that the work has been done), and spending all this time servicing dead requests guarantees that all future client requests will timeout.**

This example was presented as a way to handle multiple clients and a single server, but it simply doesn't work (I mean, if you did very quick work and had a long timeout, you would have some illusion of reliability, but it's pretty easy to envision this catastrophic collapse rearing its head under this design).

So what's a good alternative?  Yes, I could shorten the time required to do work (spinning off worker threads if needed) and increase the timeout period, but this doesn't really address the core shortcoming - just reduces its likelihood - which isn't a solution.

I just need a simple request / reply pattern that handles multiple clients and a single server that processes requests serially, in the order they're received, but in which clients can time-out reliably in the event that the server is taking too long and the server doesn't waste resources responding to defunct requests.

Comment: I could see that having clients kill all of their outgoing requests from the server's queue, before they reconnect and resend, would at least make this pattern work as advertised, but is there a way to do that with 0MQ?

Comment: Hmm, also just tried replacing the use of czmq constructs in the example with base ZMQ API and the lingering messages phenomenon has disappeared.  Maybe some socket option thing?